# Proving two blocks of code are functionally identical?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction

Let's say I start with a function, `foo()`, which is correct but poorly styled:

```
int foo(void)
{
    // Some comment
    int b;
    int    a;

    getAandB(&a, &b);

    return a+b;
}
```

I want to reformat this code block without making any functional changes:

```
int foo(void)
{
    // A more descriptive comment
    int a, b;

    getAandB(&a, &b);

    return a + b;
}
```

Is there a tool I can use to demonstrate that these two blocks are functionally equivalent?  Let's assume that re-building the whole code base is not an option, and I want to test just this code block in isolation.  I won't be able to link it because `getAandB()` is defined elsewhere.

Is it possible to use some combination of tools to prove functional equivalence in this case?

Comment: Check if it complies to same asm?

Comment: @user2802841 That is indeed an option. One must just bear in mind that it can easily produce false negatives.

Comment: To really prove these variants are **functionally** identical (i.e. doing the same things) use regression tests.

Comment: @Angew But then you check if the result is negative. I think that's still the most viable solution.

Comment: @g-makulik That's not "proving". That has the possibility of *disproving* that they're identical, but definitively proving whether or not they're identical would require [data flow analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis). I'm not sure if a suitable tool exists.

Comment: Passing the unit tests is a weaker condition than functional equivalence (since generally speaking unit tests don't test all possible inputs and don't measure all possible side-effects). You aim to make your unit tests good enough to catch all *likely* bugs, but in the rare cases where you can prove equivalence that's way better than relying solely on tests. So for example unit tests would be rather unlikely to catch the non-equivalent code `return (b != 123456 ? a + b; a);`. Your reformat is unlikely to *produce* that change, but one always suspects that subtle errors are possible.

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter There are such tools (e.g. for static code analysis). In general you're right if you have poor test cases nothing is proved at all. But usually test cases reflect the real usage of a function or component in a larger system and ensure that the functionality is correct with the given inputs. And the latter is what counts in most cases.

Comment: units test cannot work; this (refactoring-) task is known to not work (well) in C; Thats the reason why there is no refactoring tool for c, but for java and smalltalk.

Comment: Is it possible, though, to check if just this one block of code compiles to the same ASM?  As I stated in the original question, re-compiling the whole binary that this code is part of is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a bit of a problem here. Suppose `getAandB` is defined like this:

```
void getAandB(int *a, int *b) {
    if std::less<int*>()(a, b) {
        *a = 1;
        *b = 2;
    } else {
        *a = 2;
        *b = 3;
    }
}
```

Then the change you made to function `foo` quite possibly will make a difference to behaviour (since changing the order of declaration of the variables might switch their positions on the stack).

Now admittedly the behaviour that it's changing is unspecified, and quite possibly there are many innocuous changes you could make to `foo` that would alter how local variables are laid out on the stack and hence change the behaviour in the case of such a peculiar `getAandB`. But any tool you might use to test equivalence is not going to know whether or not you care about that possibility (although with the definition of `getAandB` it could perhaps rule it out).

You can use a definition of "equivalent" that allows for unspecified behaviour to change -- for example, the "as-if" rule. A lot of effort goes into knowing whether code is equivalent under the "as-if" rule, in optimizers, but generally they work by applying a sequence of transformations known to be OK, rather than by taking two bits of code and testing them.

Comment: Comparing pointers that don't point into the same array (or to the end of an array) invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @Anonymous: Not if you use `std::less<T*>()` to compare them it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

[Uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) , an open-source project might be useful for C like languages.

Another one, used a lot is [AStyle](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Good tools for testing classes are unit tests, like [boost::test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) or [cppunit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page). Test if same classes pass tests in the same way, and then they are functionally equivalent. Obviously, you must choose appropriate tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best result you would get by comparing [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) produced by compiler after translating your 2 functions. Probably easiest would be to use [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/IntroductionToTheClangAST.html) as it designed to have easy access to AST and make tools based on it.

Comment: Like for the comparison of produced asm, this might lead to many false negatives: in the example, I guess that clang would show that locals `a` and `b` are declared in opposite order.

Comment: @Virgile: *all* solutions either produce false negatives or sometimes fail to halt. Otherwise I could determine the truth or falsehood of Goldbach's conjecture by writing two simple functions and testing them for equivalence ;-) The difficulty in this case is going to be to work out what transformations on the AST are functionally equivalent and correspond to what the "reformatting" process does.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the checking the generated assembly approach, here's how you can do it.

I'm assuming your two functions are put into two files, `a.c` and `b.c`:

```
$ gcc -O0 -S a.c
$ gcc -O0 -S b.c
$ diff a.s b.s
1c1
<  .file "a.c"
---
>  .file "b.c"
13,14c13,14
<  leaq -4(%rbp), %rsi
<  leaq -8(%rbp), %rdi
---
>  leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
>  leaq -4(%rbp), %rdi
17,18c17,18
<  movl -8(%rbp), %edx
<  movl -4(%rbp), %eax
---
>  movl -4(%rbp), %edx
>  movl -8(%rbp), %eax
$
```

We turn of any optimization (-O0) to prevent any artifacts from optimization.

So somewhat surprisingly the gcc (4.1.2) output is slightly different for these two functions.  But looking at this a bit carefully we can see why - in the first function, the declaration of `b` is before `a`, so `b` is above `a` on the stack, but in the second function, it is the other way round.

So if I swap `a` and `b` I now see that the generated assembly is in fact identical:

```
$ gcc -O0 -S b1.c
$ diff a.s b1.s
1c1
<  .file "a.c"
---
>  .file "b1.c"
$
```

---

Alternatively if you only care about whether or not the generated assembly is different, and not what the generated assembly actually is, then you can do this all in one fancy-schmancy bash command:

```
$ diff --brief <(cat a.c | gcc -O0 -S -xc - -o-) <(cat b.c | gcc -O0 -S -xc - -o-)
Files /dev/fd/63 and /dev/fd/62 differ
$ echo $?
1
$ diff --brief <(cat a.c | gcc -O0 -S -xc - -o-) <(cat b1.c | gcc -O0 -S -xc - -o-)
$ echo $?
0
$
```

Comment: If you're not interested by the differences, you may just use `cmp` instead of `diff`.